# Asynchronous WebSockets in Winhttp Windows 8

Tags: asynchronous, websocket, winhttp

I want just to add WebSockets to my app that uses `WinHTTP` in async mode.

When I need a WebSocket I call the following.

1. Before sending request:

   ```
   WinHttpSetOption(context->hRequest, WINHTTP_OPTION_UPGRADE_TO_WEB_SOCKET, NULL, 0);
   ```
2. In `WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_SENDREQUEST_COMPLETE`:

   ```
   appContext->pIoRequest->hWebSocketHandle = WinHttpWebSocketCompleteUpgrade(appContext->hRequest, NULL);
   WinHttpWebSocketReceive(appContext->pIoRequest->hWebSocketHandle, appContext->pszOutBuffer,RESPONSE_BUFFER_SIZE, NULL, NULL);
   ```

all without errors.

Now I see in Fiddler that the server sends some data to my WebSocket but there is no `WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_READ_COMPLETE` triggered.

Any ideas why this is? How can I read asynchronously from my WebSocket? Sending data to the WebSocket works well.

Answer (score 3):

Omg! I found how its work!

1. You MUST call additional `WinHttpSetStatusCallback` to set WebSocket callback for `WebSocketHandle` returned in `WinHttpWebSocketCompleteUpgrade` and this callback MUST differ then that from call `WinHttpWebSocketCompleteUpgrade` was made!
2. It is no possible to set a context pointer by `WinHttpSetOption` with `WINHTTP_OPTION_CONTEXT_VALUE` flag! Its not work. `dwContext` In `WebSocketCallback` has wrong data. Call to `WinHttpQueryOption` in `WebSocketCallback`  return wrong context data. I think that is a BUG in Windows 8.1. I write my own handler to connect my context with `WebSocketHandle`.

All of this is NOT documented in MSDN! Most of all, I did not google any info about async winhttp websocket usage... So, I am the first=) I will be very glad if my research will help you!

Comment: Do you happen have a sample of the working code?
I'm running into similar issues and can't find references of async WinHTTP WebSockets.

Answer (score 0):

It seems websockets do not get PING and PONG messages to the callback!